# Help with the rest of a preamble for CV

Tags: templates

Thanks to users in this forum I have got an really good start to LaTeX and have got a lot of help with my preamble. Now I need some help at the end. :-)

Preamble so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{framed, xcolor}%to make boxes and colours

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,fix-cm,kpfonts}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}%manipulate with font size

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[left=0cm,right=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\sffamily
\noindent
\raisebox{-\fboxsep}{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr3in+2\fboxsep\relax,height=\dimexpr3in+2\fboxsep\relax]{example-image-a}}%
\colorbox{gray!50}{\parbox[b][3in][b]{3in}{\fontsize{30}{36}\bfseries\scshape\textcolor{green}{M}arie \textcolor{green}{M}uster}}%
\par
\vspace{-0.3ex}
\noindent
\colorbox{black!70}{\parbox[b][3in][b]{3in}{%
\raggedleft
\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\textsc{\LARGE Bewerbung}} als \textbf{\textsc{\LARGE Assistentin}}}\\
\textcolor{green}{\rule{2in}{0.5pt}}\\
\textcolor{white}{im \textbf{Bereich Biochemie}}
}}%
\colorbox{olive}{\parbox[b][3in][t]{3in}{%
\color{white}
Am Musterweg 22\\
12345 Musterstadt\\
Telefon 0 25 06 / 12 34 56\\
E-mail: Marie.Muser@Provider.de
}}

\end{document}
```

And it would be nice if it could look like that at the end:
[Endproduct](http://www.bewerbungsservice-aktiv.de/modules/wsShop/article.php?article_id=208786&location_id=125).

- It would be nice if someone would help me:

  to place the boxes in correct in the PDF. I thought it could use
  \centering but then I saw that on exemplary (pls see the link) it
  wasn*t in the middle. So how to place the boxes like in the exampel?

  How to change the colors with by using HTML?

Here the colors (HTML):

- color of the box right under: 5b8601

  color of the box left unde: 5a5a5a

  color of the left over box:  bfbfbf

  color of the line on the under right box and the M's in the upper
  right: box 669b03

Thank you very much so far and in advance.
PS! I used GIMP to find out which color it was.

PPS! Please just use LaTeX and not XeLaTeX or other stuff (I am a newbeginner and want to learn LaTeX at the verty begninning :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Someone in a German Forum has build it:

http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/4777/konnt-ihr-mir-bitte-helfen-eine-schone-bewerbungsvorderseite-zu-gestalten

Hope it helped?